# AngularJS(1.3.0-rc.2): data-ng-repeat-end animation issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

Im wondering why an animation will not work on the `<tr>` element in this case ([plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PcmxZ3SBCkF9kaWUEeCM?p=preview)):

```
<tr data-ng-repeat-end data-ng-show="employee.show" class="animate-show">
  <td colspan="5">
    <div class="employeeInfo">
      <img ng-src="http://placehold.it/{{employee.size}}" />Employee info
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

But will work on the `<td>` element when written like this ([plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/htrok3hHvVMjJ43RBYYB?p=preview)):

```
<tr data-ng-repeat-end  ng-animate-children>
  <td colspan="5" data-ng-show="isToggled[$index]" class="animate-show">
    <div class="employeeInfo">
      <img ng-src="http://placehold.it/{{employee.size}}" />Employee info
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Why is this happening, and what can be done to achive animation on the `<tr>` with `data-ng-repeat-end` attribute?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with version 1.3.14. Did you find a remedy?

Comment: Late comment, but if anybody is still stumbling across this issue, there was a relevant GitHub issue posted about it that has since been resolved using `ng-animate-children`. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6817